# IntelliJ Tomcat delayed war-deployment

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a way to be able to deploy war-artifacts to an IntelliJ-started Tomcat when I choose to. I have one project which has a configuration that starts a Tomcat 8 server and deploys some artifacts. LaterI now want to deploy more artifacts from different projects to that same IntelliJ-started Tomcat.

1. Step: Start project which includes the Tomcat
2. Step: Deploy war from another IntelliJ-project (from within IDE)
3. Step: Deploy another war from IntelliJ (from within IDE)

I'm having to solutions in mind but couldn't figure either out:

- Maven: so that the war file gets deployed to the tomcat
- IntelliJ-Config: that deploys the war file to the already running server

I'm looking for a possibility so that I don't need to take care of the Tomcat myself.

Comment: You can use Tomcat | Remote configuration in IntelliJ IDEA to deploy apps to the already running server (either already started from IDEA or externally, even as a service).

Answer (score 0):

You could always set up a Jenkins instance, and have it build your war every time you push to Git or Subversion, then deploy your war to Tomcat immediately after the build. Just ensure that Jenkins is running off a different port than Tomcat.